# repeating onClick event

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I would like the user to change the font style of a header with each button click. Right now it only works once. Can someone please help. Do I use a while loop?  If/else?  Sorry noob here that needs some help.
Thanks in advance.

```
const text = document.querySelector('h1');
const randomFontButton = document.getElementById('randomFontButton');

randomFontButton.addEventListener('click', () => {

let fontType = [ "Arial", "Verdana", "Helvetica","Times New Roman", 
"Times", "serif"];

let rand = fontType[Math.floor(Math.random()*fontType.length)];

text.style.fontFamily = fontType[rand];
});
```

Comment: `rand` holds the actual font type string, not a random index. It should be `text.style.fontFamily = rand;`

Comment: This question appears to be [off-topic (#2)](/help/on-topic).

Comment: You need to use a for loop. Also, too confused. What works only once? Click? Or only one h1 changes?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a while loop or if statement. Your code is mostly okay except you're setting the font incorrectly.

Change the line:

```
text.style.fontFamily = fontType[rand];
```

To:

```
text.style.fontFamily = rand;
```

You have already selected the new font with the 'rand' constraint. fontType[rand] is undefined.

```
const text = document.querySelector('h1');
const randomFontButton = document.getElementById('randomFontButton');

randomFontButton.addEventListener('click', () => {

const fontType = [ "Arial", "Verdana", "Helvetica","Times New Roman", 
"Times", "serif"];

const rand = fontType[Math.floor(Math.random()*fontType.length)];

text.style.fontFamily = rand;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help this worked also Adams solution worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
const text = document.querySelector('h1');
const randomFontButton = document.getElementById('randomFontButton');

randomFontButton.addEventListener('click', () => {

    let fontType = ["Arial", "Verdana", "Helvetica", "Times New Roman",
        "Times", "serif"];

    var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * fontType.length);
    text.style.fontFamily = fontType[idx];
});
```